# Can't install Mysql on Linux -- Mysql website failing?

Tags: mysql, yum, amazon-linux, amazon-linux-2

I'm attempting to install mysql on Amazon Linux 2. I followed the instructions in the first answer here:

[amazon linux 2 ami - aws - How to install mysql in Amazon Linux 2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/894457/amazon-linux-2-ami-aws-how-to-install-mysql-in-amazon-linux-2)

When I type:

```
sudo yum install mysql-community-server
```

I get:

```
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
amzn2-core                                                                                                               | 2.4 kB  00:00:00     
amzn2extra-docker                                                                                                        | 1.3 kB  00:00:00     
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/2/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (MySQL Connectors Community),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=mysql-connectors-community ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable mysql-connectors-community
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=mysql-connectors-community

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=mysql-connectors-community.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from mysql-connectors-community: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/2/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

So, there's a 404 error. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer you linked to is wrong, though it might have accidentally worked at the time it was posted.

MySQL does not provide RPMs for Amazon Linux (either 1 or 2). The instructions given in that answer are for CentOS 7, and only work on RHEL 7, CentOS 7, or actual identical clones (Oracle, Scientific, etc.). Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2 are *not* guaranteed to be compatible with CentOS packages, or indeed, with packages from any other distribution.

If you need to use such packages, you also need to switch your Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Michael Hampton is correct, please refer supported platforms https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/database.html, If you still want to give try check http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/ this is indexed mysql repo and find the appropriate connector url for you repo.